# Valid periods - SQL VIEW

Tags: t-sql, join, view

I have 2 tables (actually there are 4, but for now lets say it's 2) with data like this:

```
Table PersonA   
ClientID    ID  From        Till
1           10  1.1.2017    30.4.2017   
1           12  1.8.2017    2.1.2018

Table PersonB       
ClientID    ID  From        Till
1           6   1.3.2017    30.6.2017
```

And I need to generate view that would show something like this:

```
ClientID        From        Till        PersonA     PersonB
1               1.1.2017    28.2.2017    10         NULL
1               1.3.2017    30.4.2017    10          6
1               1.5.2017    30.6.2017   NULL         6
1               1.8.2017    02.1.2018    12         NULL
```

So basically I need to create view that would show what "persons" each client had in given period.
So  when there is an overlap, client have both PersonA and PersonB (same should apply for PersonC and PersonD).
So in the final view one client can't have any overlapping dates.

I don't know how to approach this.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?  Adding columns for additional values is generally poor SQL practice as it goes against set based querying principles.  If you just want a list of months and people assigned you would be better with a regular dataset that is formatted in your presentation layer.

Comment: @iamdave  - this just a task I was given. I don't like it either and I'll try to find different approach but for now I am stuck with this

Comment: Again, for what purpose?  Where will the data end up being used?  If it is going into excel for analysis you can pivot a standard dataset there.  If you have a reporting layer like SSRS you can pivot it there.  I refuse to believe you are being asked for the data in this format direct from the query for no other use?

Comment: @iamdave I don't know - but unfortunately it's already in use (legacy code) in various places. Except there is a little critical error in that view. So I am doing it from the scratch..

Comment: @quin61 can we specify that any From and Till dates are always first or last days of a period (month)? What about the value "2.1.2018" for Till in PersonA, how should that be treated if there was a follow-up interval? start next with 3.1.2018?

Comment: @dlatikay From and Till dates can be anything. In case of a follow-up interval you should group that - as long as everything else is the same. So if you have 01.01.14 - 03.01.14, and then 04.01.14 - 20.02.14, you can group them together into 01.01.14 - 20.02.14 as long as clientID, personA.Id, personB.id.. are equal - see my latest comment on the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an adaptation of [this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075717/join-overlapping-date-ranges), we can already handle the overlaps:

```
declare @PersonA table(ClientID int, ID int, [From] date, Till date);
insert into @PersonA values (1,10,'20170101','20170430'),(1,12,'20170801','20180112');

declare @PersonB table(ClientID int, ID int, [From] date, Till date);
insert into @PersonB values (1,6,'20170301','20170630');

declare @PersonC table(ClientID int, ID int, [From] date, Till date);
insert into @PersonC values (1,12,'20170401','20170625');

declare @PersonD table(ClientID int, ID int, [From] date, Till date);
insert into @PersonD values (1,14,'20170501','20170525'),(1,14,'20170510','20171122');

with X(ClientID,EdgeDate)
     as (select ClientID
               ,case
                    when toggle = 1
                        then Till
                    else [From]
                end as EdgeDate
         from
              (
              select ClientID,[From],Till from @PersonA
              union all
              select ClientID,[From],Till from @PersonB
              union all
              select ClientID,[From],Till from @PersonC
              union all
              select ClientID,[From],Till from @PersonD
              ) as concated
             cross join
              (
              select-1 as toggle
              union all
              select 1 as toggle
              ) as toggler
),merged
     as (select distinct
                S.ClientID
               ,S.EdgeDate as [From]
               ,min(E.EdgeDate) as Till
         from
              X as S
             inner join X as E
                 on S.ClientID = E.ClientID
                    and S.EdgeDate < E.EdgeDate
         group by S.ClientID
                 ,S.EdgeDate
),prds
     as (select distinct
                merged.ClientID
               ,merged.[From]
               ,merged.Till
               ,A.ID as PersonA
               ,B.ID as PersonB
               ,C.ID as PersonC
               ,D.ID as PersonD
         from
              merged
             left join @PersonA as A
                 on merged.ClientID = A.ClientID
                    and A.[From] <= merged.[From]
                    and merged.Till <= A.Till
             left join @PersonB as B
                 on merged.ClientID = B.ClientID
                    and B.[From] <= merged.[From]
                    and merged.Till <= B.Till
             left join @PersonC as C
                 on merged.ClientID = C.ClientID
                    and C.[From] <= merged.[From]
                    and merged.Till <= C.Till
             left join @PersonD as D
                 on merged.ClientID = D.ClientID
                    and D.[From] <= merged.[From]
                    and merged.Till <= D.Till
         where not(A.ID is null
                   and B.ID is null
                   and C.ID is null
                   and D.ID is null
                  )
)
select ClientID
    ,[From]
    ,case
        when Till = lead([From]
                ) over(order by Till)
            then dateadd(d,-1,Till)
        else Till
    end as Till
    ,PersonA
    ,PersonB
    ,PersonC
    ,PersonD
from
    prds
order by ClientID
        ,[From]
        ,Till;
```

Output with just the two `Person` tables given in the question:

```
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+
| ClientID |    From    |    Till    | PersonA | PersonB |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+
|        1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-02-28 | 10      | NULL    |
|        1 | 2017-03-01 | 2017-04-29 | 10      | 6       |
|        1 | 2017-04-30 | 2017-06-30 | NULL    | 6       |
|        1 | 2017-08-01 | 2018-01-12 | 12      | NULL    |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+
```

Output of script as it is above, with four `Person` tables:

```
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ClientID |    From    |    Till    | PersonA | PersonB | PersonC | PersonD |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|        1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-02-28 | 10      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
|        1 | 2017-03-01 | 2017-03-31 | 10      | 6       | NULL    | NULL    |
|        1 | 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-29 | 10      | 6       | 12      | NULL    |
|        1 | 2017-04-30 | 2017-04-30 | NULL    | 6       | 12      | NULL    |
|        1 | 2017-05-01 | 2017-05-09 | NULL    | 6       | 12      | 14      |
|        1 | 2017-05-10 | 2017-05-24 | NULL    | 6       | 12      | 14      |
|        1 | 2017-05-25 | 2017-06-24 | NULL    | 6       | 12      | 14      |
|        1 | 2017-06-25 | 2017-06-29 | NULL    | 6       | NULL    | 14      |
|        1 | 2017-06-30 | 2017-07-31 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | 14      |
|        1 | 2017-08-01 | 2017-11-21 | 12      | NULL    | NULL    | 14      |
|        1 | 2017-11-22 | 2018-01-12 | 12      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: The output I get from this query doesn't match that in the question.  You are not showing a row/period for each new combination of Persons.

Comment: thanks. the dates in OP sample data are not coherent, but I get the idea... let's try to fix.

Comment: They make sense to me, there is meant to be overlap.  The output needs to be a row for the start and end dates of each different combination of Persons with the dates that combination started and ended as well as which Persons are included.

Comment: @iamdave couldn't say it better :)

Comment: I found another answer which does something very similar (reference included in post) and adapted it for this problem - update see above. maybe we need to add a `LAG` construction yet to get the +/- one day rule right for starts and ends of months.

Comment: @dlatikay well I definitely wouldn't think of this. Very nice

Comment: @dlatikay  I have edited your script to include 4 `person` tables and also adjust the period end dates to be the day before the start of the next period, where the periods are concurrent.

Comment: @quin61  I think the script as it is now will give you what you require.  Can you test and let us know if there are any issues?

Comment: @iamdave  I thought it was perfect but than I noticed you got 2017-05-10 twice in From column. As I said there can't be no overlap in the dates for one client in the final result. Output with two person tables looks good. I'll be able to properly test it tomorrow at best. But thanks a lot - so far this is a huge help.

Comment: @quin61  How about now?

Comment: @iamdave almost perfect - but you see the rows when PersonB,C and D are not null? There are no gaps in dates so there is no reason not to group these three records together. So the outcome would be 2017-05-01  -> 2017-06-24

Comment: bah - can somebody from puzzling.stackexchange come over and have a look at this :)

Comment: Alright I guess this is close enough. Thanks for your help :)